# Separating layers in PDF files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Does anyone know of a way to use the command line in Linux to separate and merge layers (optional content, section 8.11 of [ISO 32000:2008](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) from a PDF file?

I am mostly interested in files created with Adobe Illustrator - apologies if this is too far off-topic, I am quite desperate. I've posted this also to serverfault a while back, but no answers.

I have come across a reference to cslayer.dev in [here](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.00/doc/Develop.htm#PDF_interpreter) but I cannot find any further documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any Open Source commandline utility in Linux (or on any other platform) that can separate or merge layers in PDF files.

The only commandline utility I am aware of is closed source payware: [**callas pdfToolbox6**](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en%3adeveloper%3atechnologies), which available in different incarnations:

- GUIs for Windows and Mac OS X,
- CLI for Linux/Solaris as well as for Windows/Mac.

Comment: Dear @AnonymousCoward, it would be nice to know, why you downvoted this answer. Care to give a reason in a helpful and enlightening comment?